# Grails search two child objects

Tags: grails

I have three domain objects

```
class OrgProfile {
    String name
    static mapping = {
        discriminator column:'ORG_TYPE'
     }
}

class Org extends OrgProfile {
    static mapping = {
        discriminator 'ORG'
    }
}


class Jurisdiction extends OrgProfile {
 String email
 static mapping{
   discriminator 'JURISDICTION'
 }
}
```

I need to search by name and email to get all list of Org and Jurisdiction

so something like

```
def criteria = OrgProfile.createCriteria()
criteria.list{
   or {
     ilike("name", "%${token}%")
     ilike("email", "%${token}%")
   }
}
```

where `token` is a string. How can this be achieved?

Comment: The criteria you are thinking to use should work and give you the expected result. What is the problem you are facing? Have you tried that criteria yet?

Comment: Ya guys sorry I tried it today. Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 0):

Tried the code:

```
def criteria = OrgProfile.createCriteria()
def results = criteria.list{
    or {
        ilike("name", "%${token}%")
        ilike("email", "%${token}%")
    }
}
```

Results as expected.